# Adding persistent routes to Debian 10 without restarting

Tags: debian, networking

I am trying to add a static persistent route on a Debian 10 machine without needing to restart it.
My `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug ens192
iface ens192 inet static
        address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx
        gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        dns-search domain.com
        up /bin/ip route add yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy/yy via yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

After I issue `/etc/init.d/networking restart` I lose network connectivity. A ping to any IP address throws the message `connect: Network is unreachable`.

If I reboot the machine everything - including the new static route - works fine.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to add static persistent routes without needing to restart the machine?

Comment: just enterning `/bin/ip route add yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy/yy via yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy`on the commandline?

Comment: Just entering the command on the commandline will add the route to the current routing table. But it will be deleted after rebooting the system. I am trying to add a persistent route that is still there after a reboot.

Comment: 1st add it to `/etc/network/interfaces`, 2nd enter the command in the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @stoney commented, the fully online way is adding the command to the `interfaces` file and then executing it manually as well. The alternatives of the manual execution are:

- `ifdown ens192 && ifup ens192` or
- `/etc/init.d/networking restart` after replacing `allow-hotplug` with `auto` (unless you actually rely on the hotplug functionality, of course).

Both of these inflict a short network disruption, but let you test the actual content of the `interfaces` file (only the named stanza or all of it).

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing **auto ens192** statement in your config!!!

This works for debian 9 (debian stretch), debian 10 (debian buster) and debian 11 (debian bullseye):

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` file and add your permanent routes.

Example:

```
auto ens192
allow-hotplug ens192
iface ens192 inet static
    address 192.168.221.54/24
    gateway 192.168.221.1
    dns-nameservers 82.99.137.41 212.158.133.41
    dns-search secar.cz
    up ip route del 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.221.1 dev ens192 
    up ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.221.1 dev ens192
    up ip route del 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.221.1 dev ens192
    up ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.221.1 dev ens192
```

Last step is restart network:

```
~] /etc/init.d/networking restart
# or
~] systemctl restart networking
```

Here is [completed guide for permanent debian static routes](https://www.mybluelinux.com/debian-permanent-static-routes/)